# Key bindings or workflow suggestions for managing breakpoints with pydbgr in Emacs 23.2

Tags: python, configuration, emacs, debugging

I have **pydbgr** working well now in **Emacs 23.2** with **virtualenv**. But I am confused why breakpoints are not established from the source code buffer after running **M-x pydbgr** - as they would be e.g. when using pdb.

I tried invoking <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-b</kbd> but this does not toggle breakpoints on the selected line as one would hope/expect.

Neither does <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>SPC</kbd> work as it would in pdb.

When in the *pydbgr shell* window I *can* set breakpoints according to the first keyboard short-cut above, but it is naturally far more convenient to not have to move windows in order to do this.

Also, the left buffer margin intended for setting breakpoints via the mouse does not appear by default, and the MOUSE button binding for toggling normal and temporary breakpoints do not appear to work out-of-the-box, at least with my .emacs configuration.

I am using the latest **pydbgr** and **dbgr.el** code at the time of this posting.

Can anybody with experience of using pdbgr for debugging Python application please comment on the best approaches they have adopted in this regard. Perhaps some elisp configuration code to establish key-bindings that work from the source code windows. I noticed that pydbgr does not appear to invoke a minor/major-mode within the source buffer window, so I don't know where to start implementing this myself as I have no mode-hooks to hang elisp code off.

Comment: Have you tried `C-x C-a C-b` ? If not, perhaps try `C-h b` and search for the word "break".

Comment: Could you post the exavt version of pydbgr and dbgr you are using? The sentence "I am using the latest pydbgr and dbgr.el code at the time of this posting" is not helpfull to people checking this post several years after the posting date...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent change in emacs-dbgr on http://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr adds this. There are a number of other issues regarding breakpoint synchronization. emacs-dbgr is a work in progress, not a finished product.

Comment: I did manage to set a breakpoint using C-c SPC in the end using your latest code from github, but overall I found the level of maturity of the solution too low to adopt in my normal workflow. So its back to pdb for now, I am sorry I cannot afford the time to invest further investigation into pydbgr and its associated support in Emacs at the moment. Best of luck with its refinement over the coming months.